# Screen sizes of android design in pixels?

Tags: android, dpi

As I found in `android` documentation site, the there are `4` general sizes for android devices screens. but I found the measurements unit in `dp`.
like this :

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
```

How to do that on photoshop, how to get the sizes in pixels ?
Do I need to have 4 design `ldpi`, `mdpi`, `hdpi` and `xhdpi` ? do I need to have 16 versions of the design. ?

Comment: First create images for normal screen because the 470dp X 320dp is equal to 470px x 320px.Then design the image with this [Link](http://coh.io/adpi/)  for other screens.

Comment: so for each screen size , I will have 4 designs

Comment: ya four designs.But single image is possible to set for all XML designs.

Comment: @Yugesh I mean the background design :)

Comment: how is it possible means for example 56px X 56px for mdpi is equal to 84px X 84px hdpi.hdpi is perfectly fit for 56px mdpi but if you use 56px for 84px hdpi means the pixels will be broken.

Comment: @Yugesh : your comment is little helpful, can you please clear your comment (Answer) that what you are actually trying to say. :)

Comment: @Ajay_Addon [http://coh.io/adpi/](http://coh.io/adpi/) if your button size is 56dp X 56dp in mdpi but same button in hdpi is 84dp X 84dp.If you create the image for the button in 84px X 84 px means it fit for both mdpi and hdpi.Just enter 56 X 56 in above link.you will understand easily.

Comment: @Yugesh : i have already using this link for images. see my last comment below answer..

Comment: @Ajay_Addon till you didn't understand.

Answer (score 3):

yes you have 4 designs like :

```
xhdpi = 100% image
hdpi = 75% image of xhdpi image
mdpi = 50% image of xhdpi image
ldpi = 50% image of hdpi image
```

**i.e :**

if you have 96 x 96 image in xhdpi then, you need to put

```
72 x 72 in hdpi folder - ( 75 % of xhdpi )
48 x 48 in mdpi folder - ( 50 % of xhdpi )
36 x 36 in ldpi folder - ( 50 % of hdpi )
```

Comment: I know this, but I am asking about the screen size, as I want to create a background image .. do I need 16 images in this case ?

Comment: Look at here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
MDPI is 100%, HDPI is 150% ...

Answer (score 2):

How to do that in **Photoshop**?

Just create a high res version of your image with **width and height as multiple of 16**

Then use my Photoshop **[Output Android Assets](https://gist.github.com/pdalfarr/10271735)** script to generate

- **down-scaled version of images**
- AND "**drawable-XXXX**" folders for them

Why 16 pixels? For good down-scaling results:

```
ldpi   mdpi   tvdpi     hdpi    xhdpi   xxhdpi  xxxhdpi
0,75   1      1,33      1,5     2       3       4
3      4      5,32      6       8       12      16
```

Check my SO answer here for more information:
[What is the best way to create drawables for different dpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934399/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-drawables-for-different-dpi/22966484#22966484)

Answer (score 0):

With my app I chose one screen size for it
Hdpi
And only used one image
android:background="@drawable/imagename"

If you want one for all sizes make one image
Resize it for each one 
Then edit the XML file so that it can be used by the activity

Answer (score 0):

See there are may ways,
If your background has repeating patterns you can use nine png,you ll get a lot on the internet for the same.
But if there is no repeating pattern u hve to make 4 images

to do you need to target screen fist for example you target xhdpi then its 960px*720 pixel with density per inch as 320px

now in photoshop make your all designs with considering max length as 960px and max width as 720px keep density as 320.
Now to scale change the density of images as 240 for hdpi 160 for mdpi and 120 
now your images will increase in size now scale them as mentioned by ajay in above answer

Comment: Thanks, that when I want to target screen 960px*720, what id I want to target all 4 standard screen sizes, I need to do the same . right ?