# Android Export Cropping When XXHDPI Taken as Baseline 100% In Photoshop Then How to crop means size of XHDPI, HDPI, MDPI, LDPI

Tags: android, photoshop

Android Export

```
XXHDPI - 100% baseLine
XHDPI - ?
HDPI - ?
MDPI - ?
LDPI - ?
```

Plz say anyonce of these sizes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to create drawables for different dpi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934399/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-drawables-for-different-dpi)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources

Comment: if taking baseline MDPI when exporting xxhdpi it is blured i want scaling it down or start with a XXHDPI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but don't you need the resolutions of the images?

If so, may I link you to [Android Developer support](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/guide/practices/screens_support.html)?

You can get a lot of information here:
A set of six generalized densities:

- ldpi (low) ~120dpi
- mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
- hdpi (high) ~240dpi
- xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
- xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
- xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

To create alternative bitmap drawables for different densities, you should follow the **3:4:6:8:12:16** scaling ratio between the six generalized densities. For example, if you have a bitmap drawable that's 48x48 pixels for medium-density screens, all the different sizes should be:

- 36x36 (0.75x) for low-density
- 48x48 (1.0x baseline) for medium-density
- 72x72 (1.5x) for high-density
- 96x96 (2.0x) for extra-high-density
- 180x180 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density
- 192x192 (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density (launcher icon
  only; see note above)

**Image example:**

[image: Image example for mdpi baseline]

Now, lets post this, and calculate the rest!

**Edit:**

I made a simple calculation with Excel

[image: Calculated percentages]